# How to display a japanese text with sdl 1.2, if possible

Tags: c++, text, unicode, printing, sdl

I am trying to display a japanese text with SDL 1.2 like this : jap アカツキアライヴァル. Unfortunately, the text did not display.

I enable the Unicode text display with *SDL_enableUnicode* and used *TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended*.
But only the word "jap" is displayed.

This is the part of code I used for the display :

```
SDL_EnableUNICODE(SDL_ENABLE);  //activate unicode

font = TTF_OpenFont("Japonesa.ttf", 48);

loaded = TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended(font," jap アカツキアライヴァル", color);

SDL_BlitSurface(loaded,NULL,screen,&pos);

SDL_FreeSurface(loaded);

SDL_Flip(screen);
```

Is it possible to resolve this problem ? If yes, how ?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly, but SDL 1.2 is ancient, 1.3 is even pretty old. You should use SDL 2, it also has better unicode support, and enabled by default.

Comment: How confident are you that your `" jap アカツキアライヴァル"` literal is in fact UTF8?  Pop open your debugger and check the bytes.

Comment: " jap アカツキアライヴァル" is really an UTF-8 text. I am sure. My browser (I use Firefox) can read it in UTF-8. So I do not know if it is because of SDL 1.2 itself or the content of the ttf file.

Comment: I know, that question is very old, but in case someone will have the same problem, I can suggest to check out if chosen font support your language; Looks like Japonesa is just japanese-styled, and don't support japanese symbols. I've tried another font, and this code worked just fine

Comment: @OldTeaOwl Japonesa does not support japanese symbols indeed. I found a font that support japanese characters :-)